# No module named (image_dehazer)

Tags: python, python-3.x

### **I was loading image_dehazer library, but it didn't work....
this is part of the error message and I don't know what to do !!**

```
Collecting image_dehazer
  Using cached image_dehazer-0.0.4.tar.gz (5.0 kB)
  Using cached image_dehazer-0.0.3.tar.gz (4.9 kB)
  Using cached image_dehazer-0.0.2.tar.gz (4.9 kB)
  Using cached image_dehazer-0.0.1.tar.gz (4.9 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install image-dehazer==0.0.1, image-dehazer==0.0.2, image-dehazer==0.0.3, image-dehazer==0.0.4 and image-dehazer==0.0.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    image-dehazer 0.0.5 depends on numpy==1.19.0
    image-dehazer 0.0.4 depends on numpy==1.19.0
    image-dehazer 0.0.3 depends on numpy==1.19.0
    image-dehazer 0.0.2 depends on numpy==1.19.0
    image-dehazer 0.0.1 depends on numpy==1.19.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

---

**when I checked the numpy library, it was 1.20.3**

Answer (score 0):

Try this in order:
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.19.0
pip install image-dehazer

Comment: error when tried installation https://drive.google.com/file/d/19r_xw6LSQCwqptKd-YObVFNGHGciZo5U/view?usp=sharing